# Trouble converting pdf to html or doc

Tags: android

I have been using unoconv in linux for sometime now, and it works fine for almost any document type. But when it comes to converting pdf to any other formats, say html, or doc, unoconv doesn't seem to work. It throws some error. The thing is, I am developing an android app that has a part where docs needs to be displayed. And I want the documents to be smoothly scrollable and when the user zooms in, the text should wrap. If not unoconv, any other solutions would be apprecieated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with converting from PDF to HTML as well. I did find another alternative that works just as well. It's 
[pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX). The only annoying thing is that it adds a weird border around the text in the HTML but it's well worth it.